# Customize field in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can you please tell me how to customize my components at a BlackBerry?

E.g. I need a `verticalfieldManager` which will have a label field, an image, placed one after the other. Also this `verticalFieldManager` should be in the *center of the screen*, it should not start from the immediate left or right of the screen.

I want a border for this `verticalFieldManager`, too.

Answer (score 2):

No need to customized the class. Hope, following code will solve your problem.

```
public class Sample extends UiApplication {
public Sample() {
    pushScreen(new SampleScreen());
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.enterEventDispatcher();
}
private static class SampleScreen extends MainScreen {

    public SampleScreen() {

        VerticalFieldManager vfManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        vfManager.add(new LabelField("Test Label"));
        vfManager.add(new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("image.png")));
        vfManager.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(
                new XYEdges(5, 5, 5, 5),
                Color.ORANGE,
                Border.STYLE_SOLID
            ));
        add(vfManager);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that the BorderFactory class wasn't added until JDE 4.6.0.  If you are your application on a older JDE platform then you will have to override the vertical manager's paint method to draw the border.

-Glen

Comment: You should add this as a comment to Karthik's answer, not as it's own answer.

Comment: Sorry about that however I didn't and still don't see an option to comment on Karthik's answer.  However I did see one to comment to your response.  
The only options I see on Karthik's answer are "link | flag".  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @GlenMorgan This is because you have less than 50 rep. That's why you can only comment your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create custom manager and set the position of contents as per your choice and requirement

now add your custom manager to a manager say basemanager and add this basemanager to screen